# How to shake the text field in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to shake Text field in form validation so it will be shake. 
I have tried with many animation effects for example

```
textfield.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.5, 1)
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
           cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.05, 1.05, 1)
       }
```